# bootstrapの追従機能を持つAffixプラグインがうまく機能しません

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

railsでbootstrapの機能であるAffixプラグインを実装しようとしているのですが、うまく機能しません。現状としては同ページ内においてリロードをかけると機能するのですが、一回目にページ遷移した際にはうまく機能してもらえません。affixの属性を挿入したものが固定のままになってしまいます。

左の部分をaffixで追従させて、右半分をbootstrapのoffsetで右に寄せています。

rails初心者なので基本的な箇所が抜け落ちている可能性もあります。その点も合わせて回答していただけるとありがたいです。

affixを書いた部分

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div data-spy="affix">
            <ul class="margin col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <li class="border">
                    //コード省略//
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-offset-5 col-lg-6 col-md-offset-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <h2>コメント</h2>
            <%= form_for [@article, @comment] do |f| %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
                <%= f.text_area :body, class: "...", :rows => 2 %>
                <%= f.label :image %>
                <%= f.file_field :image %>
                <%= f.submit 'コメントする' %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ページ最下部分に書いた読み込み部分

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: リンクを踏んでページ遷移するのではなく、新規タブにそのページのURLを入力してアクセスしても同じ問題が起きますか？もしこれで問題なくなるならturbolinks関係の問題のような気がするのですが。

Comment: 新規タブにURLを入力してアクセルしたところ、問題が解消したのでturbolinks‌​関係であるのではないかと推測が立てられました。もう少し自分でも調べてみます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: turbolinks‌を削除したところ、無事解決できました。ありがとうございました。